# What is the odd one out of the following JavaScript functions and why?

Tags: javascript

What is the odd one out of the following JavaScript functions and why?

```
function foo( ) {
    var a = 0; var b = 0; var c = 0;
}
function foo( ) {
    var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
}
function foo( ) {
    var a = b = c = 0;
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: The second one is the odd one, as comma seperating `var` statements like that isn't kosher.

Answer (score 0):

This 
    `var a = 0,var b = 0,var c = 0;`
should be`var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

They all have code smells.

```
function foo( ) {
var a = 0; var b = 0; var c = 0;
}
```

multiple definitions in one line.

```
function foo( ) {
    var a = 0, var b= 0, var c = 0;
}
```

creates a syntax error.

```
function foo( ) {
  var a = b = c = 0;
}
```

was said by a now-deleted answer to create the global variables `b` and `c`.